# MSMQ HTTP disable error

Tags: windows-8.1, nservicebus, msmq, nservicebus5, dism

I’m trying to install NServiceBus from installer, downloaded from particular.net

[image]

Installer wants MSMQ components to be disabled.
All components could be disabled, except the MSMQ Http support. Disabling of this component fails with error code 0x800F0922.

[image]

Trying to disable by DISM throws such error:

[image]

Dism log is:

[image]

Trying to disable it in safe mode – didn’t help.
Trying to delete all services, which use MSMQ – didn’t help.

Is there is a way to fix this issue and install NServiceBus? Cause google is not showing anything similar to my issue.
Operating system is Windows 8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try and uninstall MSMQ all together and then reinstall it again?

maybe [this can help?](https://serverfault.com/questions/554462/is-it-possible-to-enable-msmq-from-powershell-on-windows-8)

Comment: Thanks. Your link helped me to collect my thoughts :) Disabling the IIS Web Management Tools helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly create a new site with `siteId = 1` and try to install MSMQ again. You can change the default website ID to 1 as well.

[IIS site id = 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwrgK.png)